Is it possible to use Compiz as a bare compositor, aside of another window manager?
On my newer notebook, running Xorg in Suse Tumbleweed, I have spent some time to configure a window manager, customizing the toolbar, the keyboard shortcuts, etc etc, and to add a bit of eye candy I used picom.
picom can dim windows (I find it useful) and make them translucent (thank you, but no thank you), but it cannot zoom on part of my desktop, something that's very convenient when I want to show, e.g., a detail of a graph during a presentation.
I've previously asked on this site "Which X compositors, if any, support zooming?" and I was addressed to Compiz.
I'm familiar with Compiz as a window manager and compositor (my older Debian notebook runs on Compiz and everything it's OK), but…
I wonder if it is possible to use Compiz as a compositor only.
